# Сумма ряда в С++

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы, ряды

Задача. Сумма ряда от 1 до n 1/x^i
В консоль выводит ноль, не могу найти ошибку. Объясните, пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int N, x;
    double sum;
    sum = 0;

    cout << "Введите N:";
    cin >> N;

    cout << "Введите a:";
    cin >> x;

    int i = 1;
    for (; i <= N; i++)
    {
        sum += 1/x^i;
    }
    cout << "Сумма= " << sum;
}
```

Comment: Забыл написать, что мне нужно сделать эту задачу без pow()

Comment: `^` - это не возведение в степень, а побитовое исключающее или.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все было бы ничего, если бы вы учили С++ - `x^i` - это побитовое исключающее или `x` и `i`.

`pow` действительно не нужен - ведь `i+1`-й член получается делением `i`-го на `x` - так что каждый очередной член вычисляется "на ходу".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    double sum = 0, x, term;
    cout << "Введите N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Введите x: ";
    cin >> x;
    term = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        term /= x;
        sum += term;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;

}
```

Можно даже объединить вычисления `sum` и `term` в одно выражение -

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) sum += (term /= x);
```

:)

Это то, что от вас хотят. Но это же вычисляется проще - поскольку это сумма геометрической прогрессии, которая равна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такую формулу запрограммируете самостоятельно (тогда учтите, что при x==1 следует избежать деления на 0) или нужна помощь?

Раз нельзя использовать `pow`, то вычислить `x^n` можно как "в лоб" умножением, так и [быстрым возведением в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C). Или, на грани фола :), воспользоваться тем, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обработать ситуацию отрицательного значения x догадываетесь, как?